# New data screen design in light switch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I was working on creating a light switch application and i had to create a custom screen design as given by my client.I have attached a rough design (a small part) how it should be. I tried adding a screen with out creating a table and added a few custom control but was not getting it right(could not found a image button too)..Then tried adding a database and all controls were created automatically..the search field text box was disabled since it was a primary key.How to enable it.Can some one guide me how to design a custom page in light switch or point me to some tutorials or articles.Thank you.[image: Rough screen design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@karthi - you don't actually *need* a custom screen template to have a search screen like you describe (unless you have a need to add that particular type of screen numerous times). If you watch Beth Massi's video on creating custom search screens, you should get the idea.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/lightswitch/hh499661

You'll need to untick the "Support Search" box for the datagrid, so that you can use your own search criteria screens instead.

Hope that helps.

Comment: its a client requirement ..so how can i create a custom screen.Should i design it in silver light?

Comment: Did you watch the video? And you're missing the point. What I said was that you don't need to create a custom screen template to do what your client has asked you to do. The video should show you how to do what you need, if I understand yuou correctly.

Answer (score 2):

To take advantage of lightswitch you should try to make screen with light switch built in controls.

Three controls that you show in your design are avalaibles in visual studio lightswitch.

You will write rapid applications with lightswitch if lightswitch controls match for your needs, If you need to rewrite screens with silverligh then perhaps do you need a silverlight application instead a lightswitch application.

I have wrote some custom controls and sreens, I have shared code here:

- [LightSwitch Custom Control: Tree lookup Operations](http://beutil.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/lightswitch-custom-control-tree-loojup.html)
- [LightSwitch Custom Control: Tree CRUD Operations](http://beutil.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/lightswitch-custom-control-tree-crud.html)

Comment: is it possible to design screens as in those pic ....if so how??? can u please guide???is it possible to do in light switch or should i create controls in silver light and use it in light switch

Comment: its available but am unable to customize it..i need my primary key as search field but light switch creates a control thats disabled

Comment: 1) I build the screen or custom controls in silverlight then I include its in lightswitch: see: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/ 2) Perhaps you need a new database design: create a surrogate key and move your current primary key to a unique attribute.

Comment: @karthi, the problem is that with lightswitch EF you can not access to your key comlumn.

Comment: Thanks for your help dani.i have a doubt does creating custom control in silver light and including it in light switch have any negative effect in its performance?

Comment: In my opinion, custom controls have no impact over application performance.